# Where is Zymorven Hall located?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, maps

I've found two maps of the Dessarin Vale, as shown below. The left one I'm almost sure of is an official map, although I do not know where it was published. The right one is an often found map, but I'm sure is an edited version of the High-Resolution Sword Coast map. It's correct most of the time, but does contain errors here and there. Shown here you can see that where it puts "Settlestone", should have been "Winters Edge" (although not exactly). Likewise, on the official map High Hold seems to overlap with Zymorven Hall.

[image]

The thing that I'm trying to figure out is where Zymorven Hall is actually located. Ideally published map would be nice, but it may not exist. Second best is a description of where it would probably be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Storm King's Thunder* has a map](https://media-waterdeep.cursecdn.com/attachments/1/973/skt03-thenorth.jpg) unambiguously showing the location of Zymorven Hall:

[image]

Further, Chapter 3 of SKT in the section ["Locations of the North"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/skt/the-savage-frontier#ZymorvenHall) contains this description:

> Perched atop a crag overlooking the Rauvin Road, with a clear view of the Evermoors to the south and the Moonwood to the north, is a keep of mortared stone with a high-pitched roof that has wooden statues of baying wolves rising from its peaks. A branch in the road winds up to the keep’s gatehouse and bailey. From the keep, the Zymorven family of Silverymoon has watched over the surrounding lands for four generations.

So as shown on the map, Zymorven Hall is along the road pinched between the Moonwood to the north and the Evermoors to the south.

This appears to coincide exactly with the location of High Hold shown on your left map.

I was able to find a map in the 3e book *Silver Marches* which has High Hold placed at the location of Zymorven Hall, and the realm date of 3e is a little over 100 years before the time of the 5e adventures.